# netfilter - PRErouting zero copy?

Tags: routes, iptables, netfilter, zero-copy

## Context

Debian 64 bits
custom kernels 3.14-3.16

## Question

After reading a lot about port forwarding, I would like to know if nftable/iptables does zero-copy with splice(or something else) to route a packet to its destination in case the packet only matches a prerouting rule.

My assumption is "yes, of course, those guys surely have optimized such an important tool in the system"; but I am still asking.

Thanks